# Triangle Geometry Question

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> **Moderator Note:** At the time that this question was posted, it was from an ongoing contest. The relevant deadline has now passed.

I am preparing for competition math and so I found this problem I was wondering if someone could post a solution to it because I can't solve it. This is from a book in the Art of Problem Solving series I am sure some of you have heard of it.

We let ABC be a triangle with sides: AB=4024, AC=4024 and BC=2012 . We reflect the line AC over line AB to meet the circumcircle of triangle ABC at point D (D $\ne$ A). How do we find the length of segment CD?

Thanks$!$

Comment: What do you mean by D (D /ne A)?

Comment: He means $D\ne A$, that is, `D\ne A`

Comment: Mods, please delete this.This question is from an ongoing contest called online math open. http://onlinemathopen.netne.net/sites/default/files/OMOFall12.pdf See problem no. 16.Do not post solutions here . Is there a way this IP can be reported to the OMO organizers?

Comment: Actually, here's a better link: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/contest-questions-on-math-se The community consensus seems to be that if you see something, tell the _contest organisers_ about it. A "no contest question" policy would be very difficult to enforce, and as I mentioned above we _cannot_ give out the IP addresses.

Comment: This forum is suited better for olympiad problems: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/portal.php?ml=1

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is from an ongoing contest called online math open

Answer (score 6):

From the link, the contest should be over by now, so a solution definitely won't hurt.

> [image: description]

- Draw the triangle $\triangle ABC$, the reflected line $AC'$ and the circumcircle. Label the intersection of $AC'$ with the circle $D$
- Obviously $CC'$ and $AB$ form a right angle at the intersection since $AB$ is the center of reflection. Draw the segments $CC'$, $BC'$, $BD$ and $CD$.
- Label the intersection of $CD$ and $AB$ point  $E$.
- By congruency $SAS$, observe that $\triangle ABC \equiv \triangle ABC'$
- I'm treating a general case where the triangle has lengths  $2x$, $2x$, and $x$. So we have   $$\begin{align}&AB=2x\\ &AC'=AC=2x\\&BC'=BC=x \\ & \angle ABC=\angle ABC'=\angle ACB=\angle AC'B \\& \angle BAC=\angle BAC' \end{align} $$
- By inscribed angle theorem we have the following

  1. $\angle BDC =\angle BAC = \angle BAC'=\angle BCD$

     $ \implies \triangle BDC$ is isosceles and $BD=BC=BC'=x \implies \triangle BCC'$ and $\triangle BC'D$ are isosceles thus  $\angle BC'D=\angle BDC' =\angle BC'A=\angle ABC$
  2. $\angle CBA =\angle CDA = \angle BC'D$ observe that points $D$ and $C$ are on the same line thus $\angle BC'D = \angle CDA \iff CD \parallel BC' $
- Since $ED \parallel BC'$, then $\triangle ADE$ is not only isosceles but similar to triangle $ \triangle ABC' \equiv \triangle ABC$
- $\angle CEB =\angle AED =\angle ADE =\angle CBE \implies \triangle CBE$ is isosceles with $CE=CB=x$
- At this point, it is sufficient to find $DE$ in order to find $CD$.
- From similar triangles (of $\triangle BEC$ and $\triangle BCA$) we have $BE=C'D= \cfrac x2$ and $AE=AD=2x-\cfrac x2$ and by similar triangle again $\cfrac {DE}{C'D}=\cfrac {AE}{AB} \implies \cfrac{DE}{x}=\cfrac {2x-\cfrac x2}{2x}\implies DE= x-\cfrac x4$
- Finally $CD=CE+ED=x+x-\cfrac x4 =2x-\cfrac x4$
- In the case where $x=2012$, we have $CD=3521$

Answer (score -2):

This can be solved using trigonometry.  First, find the angle CAB:
$$ \angle CAB = 2 * \sin^{-1}(1006/4024) \approx 29^{\circ} $$
Now, label the intersection between CD and AB point E. Using more trig:
$$ CE = 4024 * \sin(\angle CAB) \approx 1948 $$
$$ CD = 2 * CE \approx 3896$$

Comment: it is $3521$ not $3896$